# Find sub-object of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Let's say that I have this array:

```
[ {
  id: 1,
  value: 'lorem'
},
{
  id: 2,
  value: 'ipsum'
},
{
  id: 3,
  value: 'dolor'
},
{
  id: 4,
  value: 'sit'
} ]
```

How can I return the object with the value of `dolor`?

Comment: have you tried looping through the array with .forEach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

**ES6**

```js
var arr = [{id: 1,value: 'lorem'},{id: 2,value: 'ipsum'},{id: 3,value: 'dolor'},{id: 4,value: 'sit'}];

console.log(arr.find(({value}) => value === 'dolor'));
```

**ES5**

```js
var arr = [{id: 1,value: 'lorem'},{id: 2,value: 'ipsum'},{id: 3,value: 'dolor'},{id: 4,value: 'sit'}];

console.log(arr.find(function(obj){
  return obj.value === 'dolor';
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```js
var o = [ {
  id: 1,
  value: 'lorem'
},
{
  id: 2,
  value: 'ipsum'
},
{
  id: 3,
  value: 'dolor'
},
{
  id: 4,
  value: 'sit'
} ];

var result = o.filter(function(e) {
  return e.value === 'dolor';
});
console.log(result);
```